# Do I need to close addOnSuccessListener for saving to database(setValue)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It is mentioned in this [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-2.html)

> If a listener is registered like this in an Activity, and it's not
>   removed before the Activity is destroyed, there is a possibility of an
>   Activity leak.

Should I remove this listener for saving data on realtime database in `onStop()`? or will it automatically removed after the saving operation?

```
    databaseReference.setValue(chatMessage)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    // Codes for successful!                        
                }
            });
```

Comment: to avoid memory leaks you should put that code into async and destroy the async inside on destroy of activity

Comment: Thanks for the answers dears, but what addOnSuccessListener is doing after the work finished? if it finished, it should close itself. right? what is the reason still it is active for saving operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When talking about Firebase realtime database listeners, yes, you need to remove them accordingly to the life-cycle of your activity.

Keeping your listener active, you'll end up wasting resources. So:

1. If you have added the listener in `onStart` you have to remove it in `onStop`.
2. If you have added the listener in `onResume` you have to remove it in `onPause`.
3. If you have added the listener in `onCreate` you have to remove it in `onDestroy`.

But remember `onDestroy` is **`not`** always called, so the last option in not always a good choice.

The simplest way of removing the lister would be to pass to the `addOnSuccessListener()` method as the first argument an instance of your activity. For that please see, Task's [addOnSuccessListener(Activity activity, OnSuccessListener listener)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnSuccessListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener%3C?%20super%20TResult%3E)):

> Adds an Activity-scoped listener that is called if the Task completes successfully.
>
> The listener will be called on the main application thread. If the Task has already completed successfully, a call to the listener will be immediately scheduled. If multiple listeners are added, they will be called in the order in which they were added.
>
> The listener will be automatically **removed during onStop()**.

Comment: Thanks for the answers dear, but what addOnSuccessListener is doing after the work finished? if it finished, it should close itself. right? what is the reason still it is active for saving operation?

Comment: If you are passing the as the second argument an instance of your activity, as the docs states, *the listener will be automatically removed during onStop()`. Yes, it will close itself. It is active so it can listen when the write operation completes. A Task is successful when the work represented by the task is finished, as expected, with no errors.

Comment: thank you, let's assume I save an object. and onSuccess is called. the addOnSuccessListener part is completed. right? no need for the listener after onSuccess called. (if it is a get operation, the listener is important for whole activity active state.) why it is running after its work finished?

Comment: No, the `onSuccess()` part is completed. If you pass your activity as the second argument,  the `Success Listener` will be automatically removed during `onStop()` but **not** while your app is active. If you are using a `get()` call, you are getting the data only once. With other words, once you get the data, the listener stops listening. It's the same as in case of Firebase realtime database where we have the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` method.

Comment: hi, in my case I am using save operation in another java class(not in activity class). therefore passing activity as an arg is not possible. what is your suggestion to close that listener for saving operation?

Comment: Why so you say it's not possible? It is! I assume you are setting that value within a method in a non-activity class, which is basically called from within your activity class. In this case simply pass an instance of you activity as an argument to that method when you are calling it. That's it.

Comment: thank you it is a super solution. and my last question. why there is no addListenerForSingleValueEvent for saving operation? if there is an addListenerForSingleValueEvent, then no need to worry about a closing thing. right?

Answer (score 1):

The blog goes on to tell you exactly what you need to do to prevent an activity leak.  You can either remove it yourself, or you can use an activity-scoped listener (passing the activity as the first argument on `addOnSuccessListener()`) that's automatically removed when the activity is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for the answers dear, but what addOnSuccessListener is doing after the work finished? if it finished, it should close itself. right? what is the reason still it is active for saving operation?